# How to get "city" field from Clients table in laravel query properly?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

```
public function FindDomainDependCityClient(Request $request) {
         $city = Client::select('city')
              ->where('clients.id', '=', $request->id)
              ->get();
```

the query above doesn't get any result, otherwise if i replace ($request->id) with 'casablanca' (the city) in mysql phpMyAdmin I get the result

```
    $data = Domaine::select('id_domain', 'nom_domain')
            ->where('Domaines.city', $city)
            ->get();

    return response()->json($data);
```

I use Jquery & Ajax to get the data

```
$(document).on('change', '#id', function() {
    var id = $(this).val();

    $.ajax({
        type: 'get',
        url: '{!! URL::to('/finddomaindependcityclient') !!}',
        data: {'id': id},
        success: function(data) {
            console.log('success !!');
            console.log(data);
            console.log(data.length);

            var fillDropDown = '<option selected disabled>Sélectionner le domaine</option>';
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                fillDropDown += '<option value="'+ data[i].id_domain + '">' + data[i].nom_domain + '</option>';
            }
            $('#id_dom').html(""); //clear input values
            $('#id_dom').append(fillDropDown);
        },
        error: function(msg) {
            console.log('error getting data !!');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Whats in `$request->nrc`?

Comment: is the : $(document).on('change', '#id', function() {
        var nrc = $(this).val();

Comment: Now you edited to `$request->id` .. What's the actual content of this variable?

Comment: is the value of select option {{client->id}}

Comment: The content, not the source. Use `var_dump()`, `dd()`, `print_r()`.

Comment: the content of $request->id is the id : 1

Comment: Do you have a Client with `id = 1`? That's what your query does.

Comment: No, I would select from dropdown a client , then with ajax I want to get the city of selected client, and get all domains with the same city of the client in the query to fill "domains" dropdown

Comment: why ->get() instead of first? are you sure you have a client id = 1 in your db?

Comment: I used first() but it doesnt work also, and Im suure I have a client with id == 1

Comment: When I put in mysql this query I get the result of client city with (select city from clients where clients.id = 1

Comment: and in the domain (laravel query) Domaine::select('id_domain', 'nom_domain')
            ->where('Domaines.city', $city)
            ->get(); ............ when I replaced $city with 'casablanca' that's work

Comment: make this query like `$city = Client::find($request->id)->city;` and check what you get from it.

Comment: THANNN UUUUUU THAT SOLVED MY PROBLEM, ANSWER THE QUESTION BELOW AND I WILL MARK YOUR QUESTION AS THE APPROPRIATE SOLUTION

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to get city name from `Client` model. as you are using `get()` that gives you a collection and your next query is not working. So do it like

```
$city = Client::find($request->id)->city;
```

and then get the domains related to the city

```
$data = Domaine::select('id_domain', 'nom_domain')
            ->where('city', $city)
            ->get();
```